# Using DISTINCT in wp_query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I need to create a system where the user first selects the state, then select the city and then see the information of the stores in that city.

For this, I created a cpt called store with 2 meta boxes: state and city.

For the first drop-down list, I'm using a wp_query with the following args:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'store',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'state',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
    'order' => ASC,
);
```

But it is returning repeated states, because there is more than one store in the same state.

How can I solve this? I thought about using mysql DISTINCT but do not know if it is possible.

**UPDATE**

The complete loop:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'store',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'state',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
    'order' => ASC,
);

 function search_distinct() { return "DISTINCT"; }
 add_filter('posts_distinct', 'search_distinct');
 $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

 if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
   echo '<ul>';
   while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
      $the_query->the_post();
      echo '<li>' . get_custom_field('estado') . '</li>';
   }
   echo '</ul>';
 }
 wp_reset_postdata();
 remove_filter('posts_distinct', 'search_distinct');
```

But the filter is not taking effect

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried it myself, but that sounds like something for the `posts_distinct` or `posts_groupby` filters:

```
function search_distinct() {
    return "DISTINCT";
}
add_filter('posts_distinct', 'search_distinct');
```

Comment: Hey Pim. How can I connect this filter with the query?

Comment: You'd need to combine it with wordpress conditionals, depending on where you want to use the query (for instance is_post_type_archive('store') ), or you could include the filter directly in your template so it's only called there.

Comment: I will use this query in a simple loop.

Comment: Try to include it right before the query, then call `remove_filter('posts_distinct', 'search_distinct');` right after the loop is finished.

Comment: I add the filter as you said (see above) but nothing happens.

Comment: With your updated code, it's a different story entirely... you say the *state* is being repeated right? So no need for "distinct" posts. But what is `get_custom_field()`? That doesn't seem very standard.

Comment: Does your query actually produce duplicate "store" posts? Or is the meta just being repeated?

Comment: get_custom_filed() is a function to retrieve post meta values.

Comment: For example: I have three store. One on SP and two on MG. The query return SP, MG, MG.

Comment: And what is the problem exactly? That is the expected result of that query. The query isn't returning states, you have 3 stores so it returns 3 results. You are querying posts. How would you want it to behave? Only return one post per state? Based on what conditions? Your question is too unclear.

Comment: You're right. So I transfrom states and cities in taxonomies. Thanks.

Comment: @Pim Thanks for this answer, just what I needed on a project

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the best way to achive this, but you can use a raw query like this:

```
$states = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value 
                              FROM wp_postmeta 
                              WHERE meta_key = 'state'
                              ORDER BY meta_value");
```

The above will return an array of unique `state` metadata values, which you then can display in a list using:

```
if (count($states)) {
  print '<ul>';
  foreach ($states as $state) {
    print '<li>' . $state->meta_value . '</li>';
  }
  print '</ul>';
}
```